# Sprites not loading

Tags: java, image, graphics

Me and a partner have been creating a game for our class. And while we are able to make shapes, we are unable load the sprite. I'm not sure all this code is  necessary but it seemed like the necessary classes, and any other help with our code here would be most appreciated.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BoardGraphics extends JPanel{
public BoardGraphics(){
    initGraphics();
}
//Image Url's
String grassTS = "src/Resources/Sprites/GrassTile_1.png";
//Image objects

BufferedImage grassTI;

public void layTiles(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 21; k++){

        }

    }
}

public void loadImage(String url, Image image){

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
        if(image != null){
            System.out.println(url + ", has been loaded!");
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

public void initGraphics(){

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    loadImage(grassTS, grassTI);

}
public void drawPlayer(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(5,5,32,32);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawImage(grassTI,21,21,null);

    drawPlayer(g);

    layTiles(g);

}
}
```

My partner has done most of this code, and I know very little about graphical programming in java. Also i'm trying to split these two classes apart.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

boolean running = true;

public final int Wid = 480;
public final int Hei = 480;
public final int scale = 3;
public final String name = "Hasty Harvester";

private JFrame frame;

JFXPanel in = new JFXPanel();
public Board b;
public KeyIn input;
public BoardGraphics g = new BoardGraphics();

public boolean start = true;

public Game(){
    init();
    frame = new JFrame(name);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Wid, Hei));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    input = new KeyIn(in);
    frame.add(in);
    frame.add(g);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void run(){

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double ns = 100000000.0 / 60.0;

    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;

    Farm farmville = new Farm("src/Resources/Levels/levels.txt");
    b = farmville.getMap(0);
         music("src/Resources/Music/CasualGameTrack_Alexandr_Zhelanov_Ingame.mp3");

    while(running) {

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        boolean shouldrender = false;

        while (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            tick(b);
            delta--;
            shouldrender = true;
        }

        if(shouldrender) {
            frames++;
            render();
        }

        //Per second record the amount of frames + ticks, and reset them
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer +=1000;
            System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + ", Ticks:" + ticks);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }


    }
}

public void init(){
    in.setFocusable(true);
}

public void music(String mus){
    Media sung = new Media(Paths.get(mus).toUri().toString());
    MediaPlayer med = new MediaPlayer(sung);
    med.play();
}

public void tick(Board b){
    if(input.up.isPressed() == true){
        System.out.println("Up");
        input.up.toggle(false);
        b.movePlayer("Up");
    }
    if(input.down.isPressed() == true){
        System.out.println("down");
        input.down.toggle(false);
        b.movePlayer("Down");
    }
    if(input.right.isPressed() == true){
        System.out.println("right");
        input.right.toggle(false);
        b.movePlayer("Right");
    }
    if(input.left.isPressed() == true){
        System.out.println("left");
        input.left.toggle(false);
        b.movePlayer("Left");
    }

}


public void render(){

}

public void start(){
    new Thread(this).start();
    running = true;
}

public void stop(){
    running = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Game().start();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was in the loadImage method as it was loading the image into a new image object.